# Связка Qt/C++ и QML

Tags: qt, qml

Начал интересоваться QML. Сам по себе QML, я так понимаю, не так уж и хорош, его нужно использовать в связке с C++, т.е. QML - интерфейс, C++ - логика программы. Но возник вопрос, интерфейс нужно писать полностью с помощью QML, или отдельные элементы? Просто мне кажется, что если смешивать с виджетами, то получается какой то быдлокод, а с другой стороны, в виджетах есть удобный QMainWindow, который, мне кажется, на QML написать труднее, и те же QTableWidget и QTableView. Как все таки грамотнее использовать связку QML+C++, что бы это было красиво?

Comment: Я смешивал т.к. мне нужны были QStackedWidget и QToolbox на андройде и на десктопе, а у qml библиотека компонентов пока различна для разных систем что добавляет геморроя. Хотя программу я начал писать еще в 4.7, а там qml выводился через QDeclarativeView который все равно потомок QWidget, да и вообще qml был вставлен уже потом

Comment: @aknew, т.е. по сути, QML можно встраивать в проект в качестве отдельных виджетов QDeclarativeView? Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: да, я именно так сделал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот здесь пример использования связки QML + C++: https://projects.developer.nokia.com/guitartuner

Теоретически, можно и виджеты вывести в QML, попробуйте.